# Simple Navigation and passing data among Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 Activities. Assume them as 1,2 and 3.

Each screen contains-

1. Screen Name - screen_1, screen_2 and screen_3 resp.
2. From screen # - # is screen_number passed among Activities.
3. Next button - To navigate to next Activity.

   - The navigation as follows below-

1->2->3
and Vice versa
3->2->1

[image: Navigation as in picture]

- The 'From_screen_#' for 'Screen 1' will be blank or '0' at every launch.
- When I press next button on Activity_1 It should navigate to Activity_2 with From_screen_# as '1'. If I press back button on Activity_2 then the From_screen_# should be '2' in Activity_1.
- Similar behavior on Activity 2.
- In Activity_3 onClick of next button it should navigate to Activity_2 and pass From_screen_# as '3'. So that on Activity_2 the From_screen_#  is '3'. when I press back button on Activity_2 it should navigate to Activity_1 and not to Activity 3.
- I cannot use Hardcoded navigation like Overriding onKeyDown() and starting previous Activity via Intent.

I Started NextActivity as below-

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Two.class)
            .putExtra("from", "1"), 2);
```

I have overridden onKeyDown() and passed data to previous Activity as below-

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("from", "2");
        setResult(2, intent);
        finish();
}
```

I set From_screen_# in onActivityResult() as below-

```
if(data!=null)
        txtFrom.setText("From" + data.getStringExtra("from"));
```

On 3rd Screen I started 2nd Activity as below-

```
startActivity(new Intent(Five.this, Two.class)
                    .putExtra("from", "3")
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

Query-

if I navigate from 1->2 and then from 2->1 I get correct From_screen_# = 1.

But when I navigate from 1->2->3 then from 3->2 and then from 2->1 then the data is null on Activity_1. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it can't be done!!!

1. At launch Activity_1 is on Stack. It starts Activity_2 and Pushes it onto stack.
2. Now Activity_2 starts Activity_3 and Pushes it onto stack.

so now the stack contains 3 Activities. I can pop Activity from stack using Flag "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP". This will re-create the Intented Activity.

In my case it is Activity_2 so it receives data from Activity_3. Now that this Activity_2 is re-created from Activity_3 so it cannot pass any data via Intent to Activity_1 without recreating it.

I tried setting launch_mode on Activity_2 = singleTop which avoid recreating Activity_2. In that case the data cannot be passed from Activity_3 to Activity_2. But the intended data is passed successfully from Activity_2 to Activity_1.

I think we can only pass data to and fro via Intent.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you would like to override the default Android behavior when pressing the back button, you must override `onBackPressed` in your activity. `onKeyDown` is for watching events from the keyboard.

You have no content when resuming Activity #1 because there is no data in your intent (no data are passed from 2 to 1). You ought to investigate if there is any in `onResume`.

It is nice to learn how to use intents to pass data from a context to another. However, as you may have noticed, it is not really to use them. Passing custom objects is tough as well.

I strongly advice you to use a library such as [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler).

To solve your issue, simply pass data when pausing the source activity and pull them when resuming the destination one.

Comment: I have edited the Question and simplified the Language. Let me know if you have any doubts in understand the question.